# Android SeekBar Addition Issues

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

**EDIT:** I also have pre-existing elements within my app that also add to the counter, so assigning `counter = progress` would just override the sum instead of adding to.

```
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDemo);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        seekBarTextView.setText("Tracking: " + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
        counter += progress;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

});
```

I'm having an issue with getting a `counter`to obtain a value off the seekbar. It is fine when you drag it to where you want to at first, but lets say from a scale of 1 - 10 and you are changing your mind consistently from 1 to 4 to 10 to 7.

7 appears on my TextView but the value I get when passing it to my counter is the sum of all of the numbers, where in this example, I would get 22.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's because you are using `+=`. If you just want the current value, remove the `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`counter += progress;`

Is the same as `counter = counter + progress`.

First pass: `counter = 0 + progress // let's say progress = 7`

Second pass: `counter = 7 + progress // let's say progress = 5, counter is now = 12...`

If you just want the current value of the slider, you want to use `counter = progress;`

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply. This does work in this scenario but my issue with this is that I also have other parts of an app that have radioboxes that add to the counter. So when I click through the seekbar with an already existing value in my counter, `counter = progress` would then override the counter.

I understand I gave a really shallow background of the issue, so I apologize for that.

**EDIT:** I solved the issue by setting the seekbar to be the first thing to add to the counter. Not sure if this is the way to do it or if its a workaround but it works.